# 'read' command for unix not working without while loop even for single line input

Tags: bash, unix

I am not able to understand why the read command is not working without the while loop as shown in the code below. I referred this [Using “while read…” in a linux script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604626/using-while-read-in-a-linux-script) question where the answer also mentioned that since the input is a single line

> This is to say that having a while loop here is not really accomplishing anything.

```
 55 echo "Some sample text" | read var1 var2
 56
 57 echo "Var1: ${var1}"
 58 echo "Var2: ${var2}"
 59
 60 echo "----------------------------"
 61
 62
 63 echo "Some sample text" | while read v1 v2
 64 do
 65        echo "Var1: ${v1}"
 66        echo "Var2: ${v2}"
 67 done
 68
 69 echo "----------------------------"
```

Output:

```
Var1:
Var2:
----------------------------
Var1: Some
Var2: sample text
----------------------------
```

Comment: you send three arguments "Some", "sample", "text" but read in two variables.

Comment: The commands in a pipeline are executed in a subshell, variable changes don't affect the original shell.

Comment: @kofemann The last variable gets all the remaining words.

Comment: `shopt -s lastpipe` for that to work or just use a herestring `read -r var1 var2 <<< 'some sample text'`

Comment: @kofemann, the number of given variables is not the problem, it will work even with just one variable, subshell is the culprit.

Comment: Well, even without a variable the builtin variable `$REPLY` will/should catch all that is given to `read`

Comment: @Jetchisel I tried the $REPLY as will and it doesn't catch the input aswell.

Comment: `subshell` is the problem you need to solve, and everything will work out....